# Display asp:content in multiple locations?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, umbraco

I'm working with ASP.NET masterpages, and I'd like it so that a template can specify a page title ONCE and this is then used in both the `<head><title>Title Element</title></head>` and also the `<h1>Page Header</p1>`.

I found a piece of code that appeared to do what I wanted, but I believe it was in VB instead of C# so I adapted it a little:

```
<asp:content ContentPlaceHolderId="Head" runat="server">
  <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder Id="Title" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder></title>
</asp:content>

<asp:content ContentPlaceHolderId="PageHeading1" runat="server">
  <%
    LiteralControl title = Title.Controls.Item(0).Text;
    Response.Write(title.Text);
  %>
</asp:content>
```

This code gives me the following error:

```
CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.ControlCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.ControlCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I'm very new to ASP.NET and Umbraco, so please go easy on me.

Thanks,

YM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# uses square brackets for indexers.

Change

```
LiteralControl title = Title.Controls.Item(0).Text;
```

to

```
LiteralControl title = Title.Controls[0].Text;
```

The error is saying the compiler cannot find a *method* called Item, which does not exist on ControlCollection.

This is worth a read, it's for older versions of C# but still a useful grounding - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288462(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288462%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that VB didn't use square brackets. I had just assumed that Item *was* a method.

Comment: Okay, so that kinda works, except for the text is now printed at the top of the page. Is there a function I can use instead of Response.Write() that will output to the asp:content block instead?

Comment: This sounds like a separate question; you should ask a new question for it.

Comment: I used something like <%= "test" %> in the end.